# Remove Elementor Menu From Wordpress Admin

Tags: admin-menu

How to remove elementor from wordpress admin menu. I have tried below option but it didnt work.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=elementor_library' );                   
    //Elementor
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This would work for editors. You can swap the role in and out depending on which role you are trying to target (e.g., `editor`, `subscriber`, etc.). This would go in `functions.php` of your child theme.

```
function remove_menus(){
// get current login user's role
$roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

// test role
if( !in_array('editor',$roles)){
return;
}

//remove menu from site backend.
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=elementor_library' ); // Elementor Templates
remove_menu_page( 'elementor' ); // Elementor
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' , 100 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do it using `'admin_init'` action. The correct code is below

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {

global $user_ID;

if ( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) ) 
{
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=elementor_library' );
remove_menu_page( 'elementor' );
}
}
```

However, I am not able to restrict it for a specific user role. The above code restricts it for all user roles, including admin.

I am using a multisite install. so if anyone knows to restrict it for a user role on multisite install, please add the necessary bit of code.

Thanks.

Comment: You should NOT use roles with `current_user_can` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can): "While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results."

Comment: Even an admin "can" subscriber. To hide it for everyone except admins, change the condition to `if(current_user_can('activate_plugins'))`.

Answer (score -1):

This code works for admins only.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages($query) {
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if($current_user->ID == 1) //Aqui é o meu ID. Vai ocultar a página pra todos menos pra esse ID
                return $query;
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=elementor_library' );
remove_menu_page( 'elementor' );
}
```

Comment: The user ID and the role are not related. User nr. 1 might be just a normal user.